# How can I create several folders?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dir, mkdir

How can I create several subfolders in folder in one command.

For example, I want to create:

```
/home/user/*create dir1*/*create dir2*/*create dir3*/
```

Provided, I don't have dir1. And I can't use 3 command, and can't use shell script. 
This creating must be in one shell command.

```
$ mkdir /home/user/TEST1/TEST2/TEST3/
```

Doesn't work, no such file error. If

```
$ mkdir /home/user/TEST1/
$ mkdir /home/user/TEST1/TEST2/
$ mkdir /home/user/TEST1/TEST2/TEST3/
```

That work's, but I can't implement that solution. I need to use just one command.

Could you give me answer for this trouble?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the -p argument:

```
-p, --parents 
no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

so the command you need is:

```
$ mkdir /home/user/TEST1/TEST2/TEST3/ -p
```